# Python: user input not registering as dic

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

does anybody know how to make python take user input as dic name?

```
from list import dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4

country = input("Where do you live? ")
new_country = country.capitalize()
print(f"{new_country} is a great country to live in!")

if new_country in dic1:
    country_value = dic1.get(new_country, "")
    city = input("Which city? ")
    new_city = city.lower()
        if new_city in country_value:
            population = country_value.get(new_city, )
            print(population)
        else:
            print("not found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Basically in dic1 there are country: "dic2", country: "dic3" etc so by putting country you get value which is name of other dics available.

The issue is that it does not go through second 'if' properly and always goes into 'else' of it. The code itself runs if I run it by putting dic2, dic3 etc instead of country_value even tho if I print country_value it gives me dic2, dic3 etc.

Any ideas why python is not accepting it?

Comment: The *name* of a dictionary is not something that you can call `.get()` on, or do anything else whatsoever that requires a dictionary.  You should put these other dictionaries directly in `dic1`, rather than their names.

Comment: It you have a module called `list.py`, call it something else, because you might otherwise be tempted at some point to use `import list` and then find that you have overridden the `list` builtin. (You just about get away with it when using `from list import ...`.)